# Selenium web drivers giving error while calling in uwp winui 3 desktop Application

Tags: c#, selenium, uwp

how selenium work in UWP with winui 3 in desktop application. the error which is giving me is.what i have tried and the error is
**The code is**
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\App1
        \ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
       
    }
```

**The Error is**

OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: 'The file C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\App1\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe does not exist

Comment: two questions 1. `is chromedriver.exe` really present in that location. 2. Do you have admin access, cause C:\Users\Admin looks to be sensitive directory.

Comment: yes i have both but still giving me error

Comment: Can you try placing that in a different directory like D:\somwhere and see if that works

Comment: i have do that but same error

Comment: Is there issue with the app i mean is selenium driver compatible with uwp winui 3 desktop app ?

Comment: lastly can you place that in you System path, and launch webdriver like this : ` IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234314/discussion-between-fazal-abbas-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Well I am not sure about  `uwp winui 3 desktop app ?`, But does that app is a desktop application ? FYI selenium is for web browser autoamtion

Comment: application is Desktop